# How to prevent tabs and line-breaks from becoming spaces?

Tags: html, css

When you use line breaks and tabs, they appear as whitespace in document. Sometimes I want to keep elements on separate lines for tidiness. But I don't want a space:

```
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div><div>3</div>
</body>
```

(implying inline-block) renders as

```
1 23
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/uaz2kb74/1/

Answer (score 1):

Either you minify your code or mark everything outside html elements as comments

```
<body><!--
  --><div>1</div><!--
  --><div>2</div><div>3</div><!--
--></body>
```

[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uaz2kb74/2/)

Comment: untill they make support for `white-space-collapse: discard` in CSS you're solution is probably the nicest one on the market.

Answer (score 0):

Anything displaying inline will count white spaces within it as an actual space.

If you wanted to work around it, in that example, you could apply `font-size: 0;` to the body, and then give each div an non-zero font size.

That's the easiest way, but for anything larger than that example you'd want to be a bit more specific about applying that 0 font-size.

Here's a working example, https://jsfiddle.net/uaz2kb74/3/

A comprehensive list of solutions to this inline block element space by David Walsh is [here](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block), and else where on the web and stack overflow as it's a pretty common problem!